# VBA transpose column vector by delimiter and include nullstrings

Tags: list, vba, sorting, optimization, excel

Below is an example of my data (column vector):

NAME

A

B

C

A

B

C

[blank cell]

B

C

NAME

A

B

C

Note that the [blank cell] in my document is actually just a blank cell, no formula data etc.

Ultimately, I just need to transpose the data delimited by NAME. NAME cells are the only cells with:

```
Left(rngCell.Value, 2) = Left(StrConv(rngCell.Value, vbUpperCase), 2)
```

My code is breaking my transpose and making a new row for all NAME and all [blank cell]s.

I'm trying to get:

```
NAME A B C A B C   B C

NAME A B C A B C A B C

NAME A B C   B C   B C
```

But my code is returning:

```
NAME A B C A B C

B C

NAME A B C A B C A B C

NAME A B C

B C

B C
```

Here is the code I'm using:

```
Sub Dataclean()

Dim lngRowLast As Long, _
lngRowPaste As Long, _
lngColOffset As Long
Dim rngCell As Range, _
rngDataSet As Range
Dim strSourceTab As String, _
strOutputTab As String

 'Tab name containing source data.  Change to suit.
strSourceTab = "sheet2pull"
 'Tab name for data output.  Change to suit.
strOutputTab = "transposed"

lngRowLast = Sheets(strSourceTab).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

 'Assumes the original dataset is in Column A and starts at Row 1.  Change to suit.
Set rngDataSet = Sheets(strSourceTab).Range("A1:A" & lngRowLast)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each rngCell In rngDataSet

    If Left(rngCell.Value, 2) = Left(StrConv(rngCell.Value, vbUpperCase), 2) Then
        If lngRowPaste = 0 And lngColOffset = 0 Then
            lngRowPaste = 1
            lngColOffset = 1
        Else
            lngRowPaste = lngRowPaste + 1
            lngColOffset = 1
        End If
    ElseIf lngRowPaste = 0 And lngColOffset = 0 Then
        lngRowPaste = 1
        lngColOffset = 1
    End If

    Sheets(strOutputTab).Cells(lngRowPaste, lngColOffset).Value = rngCell.Value
    lngColOffset = lngColOffset + 1

Next rngCell

Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

Please let me know if I've been unclear or confusing. I tried to be as explicit as possible, but it's often tough to explain! Thank you so much.

I'm a bit new to VBA, but learning.

Comment: add this(after your first IF word): rngCell.value <> "" And

Comment: Thanks! Feel free to post this to answers and I'll give it a check!

Answer (score 0):

You error is when the first if is comparing a blank. This will always be true as a blank and uppercase blank aare equal. Replace your first if with the below.

```
If Left(rngCell.Value, 2) = Left(StrConv(rngCell.Value, vbUpperCase), 2) And _
    Not IsBlank(rngCell.Value) Then
```